# How to create account for PowerBI or other application to grant access using AAD

Tags: azure-active-directory

I am currently using AAD groups to give access to  my azure sql database.
Some i give DB role based, some database contained for schema specific access.

Now i have few accountID for PowerBI, Denodo and multiple other application access. Currently these are created as SQL logins..

Is there a way i replace them somehow to use the AAD groups for them as well. If so, can you pl help me with step by step document/artifact.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "using AAD groups to give access to my azure sql database"? Can you explain it in detail so that we can judge whether your needs are feasible.

Comment: Azure Active Directory Groups. I create lets say <DBName>_Reader group and add members to that group. In the Azure SQL DB PaaS, i create a database contained DM_DataReader role access to that group. In that way, i manage access using AAD groups than by creating SQL Logins for users and managing their passwords etc.,,